# JabberClient: App crashes when receiving a message

Tags: xmppframework

I’m following a pretty old tutorial for a JabberClient for iOS. Worked out fine till now.
I can send messages to other users but as soon as somebody writes me a message the app crashes with following message.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: msg)‘

Here is the code for the method to receive a message.

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{

    NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];

    NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
    [m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];

    [_messageDelegate newMessageReceived:m];
}
```

The problem seems to be the elementForName: method of the XMPP framework. See the definition and the comments of that method.

```
- (NSXMLElement *)elementForName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSArray *elements = [self elementsForName:name];
    if ([elements count] > 0)
    {
        return elements[0];
    }
    else
    {
        // There is a bug in the NSXMLElement elementsForName: method.
        // Consider the following XML fragment:
        //
        // <query xmlns="jabber:iq:private">
        // <x xmlns="some:other:namespace"></x>
        // </query>
        //
        // Calling [query elementsForName:@"x"] results in an empty array!
        //
        // However, it will work properly if you use the following:
        // [query elementsForLocalName:@"x" URI:@"some:other:namespace"]
        //
        // The trouble with this is that we may not always know the xmlns in advance,
        // so in this particular case there is no way to access the element without looping through the children.
        //
        // This bug was submitted to apple on June 1st, 2007 and was classified as "serious".
        //
        // --!!-- This bug does NOT exist in DDXML --!!--
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I don’t quite understand that XML fragment they’re posting there.
Did anybody have a similar issue or knows a solution how I could possibly fix that?